# Publish pipeline artifact to Slack

Tags: azure-devops, build-pipeline, azure-pipelines, artifacts, slack

I have a pipeline on Azure DevOps that publishes an artifact (`releasenotes.txt`).

It also has integration with Slack using ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/slack?view=azure-devops ) .

How can I send `releasenotes.txt` to Slack? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stock *Azure Pipelines app for Slack* does not support that workflow of uploading artifacts to Slack. You could use [this marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kasunkodagoda.slack-notification) task and upload your release notes artifact with it.

Bonus points suggestion, if you are going down the release notes path I would take a look at using Richard Fennell's [Generate Release Notes task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-XplatGenerateReleaseNotes) in combination with the [Wiki Updater task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-WIKIUpdater-Tasks).

You can create a generalized Task Group or yaml template that you could pretty much re-use anywhere. For example in the Wiki updater task you can create a release name wiki page formatted like:
`$(Build.Repository.Name)\$(Release.EnvironmentName)\$(Release.ReleaseName).md`

And then in your Slack message send a generalized link to your release notes.
`Release Notes Wiki link <https://collection-name.visualstudio.com/projectname/_wiki/wikis/Release-Notes?wikiVersion=GBmaster&pagePath=$(Build.Repository.Name)\$(Release.EnvironmentName)\$(Release.ReleaseName)|$(Release.EnvironmentName)\$(Release.ReleaseName)>`

You could push them back into the Repo that the release originated from or a central release notes repository. Your release notes get source controlled and are nicely organized!